# Server Object Model: Retrieve alerts for a folder in Doc Library

Tags: alert

I need to find out if a user has alert set for a folder within Document Library. Can someone please advise how to do so?

I am able to do so for Folder Items but not for the folder itself.

Thanks

MS

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/56f503f1-fc8e-4d4d-bee5-450e0f8726e3?prof=required). Do you know the user name? you could perhaps reverse engineer the example in the link to do what you need.

Cheers,

Alex